# Dynamic variable name for a multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming

On my left hand I've got this "key" :
`localisation.adresse.commune.id`
and many other values like this one, wich are dynamics (i can't use them literraly in my code as i don't know what they will be).

On the other hand i have an array like this (comes fron a json decoded) :

```
    Array
        (
            [localisation] => Array
                (
                    [adresse] => Array
                        (
                            [adresse1] => Le Chatelard
                            [codePostal] => 42820
                            [etat] => France
                            [commune] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 16418
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

I can't list all the "keys" i'm going to exploit, so I need to automatically get the value of $object['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id'].

I've tried this but it does not work :

```
$test['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id'] = 16418 ;
$var = '$test[\'localisation\'][\'adresse\'][\'commune\'][\'id\']' ;
echo $var ; // $test['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id']
var_dump($$var) ; // NULL Notice: Undefined variable: $test['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id']
var_dump(${$var}) ; // NULL Notice: Undefined variable: $test['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id']
```

I suppose it's looking for a simple variable of a complicated name, instead of looking at a multidimentional array, but i don't know how i can do it...

Thans for your help !

Comment: you need to decode that json string in array by json_decode

Comment: I already did it, with \GuzzleHttp\Utils::jsonDecode($objet, true);. That's not the real problem here, i could have removed the json part from the question, i already have an associative array : `Array ( [localisation] => Array ( [adresse] => Array ( [adresse1] => Le Chatelard [codePostal] => 42820 [etat] => France [commune] => Array ( [id] => 16418 ) ) ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no other way except traversing the array and trying to find the keys in internal arrays, if there are any.

I came up with two variants: recursive and iterative. They will also handle the case when the "depth" of the key and array differ, e.g. if your `$key` will contain more elements than the depth of the array, then the `NULL` will be returned, if less - then whatever is under the last key will be returned.

#### Recursive variant

```
$a = [
    'localisation' => [
        'adresse' => [
            'adresse1' => 'Le Chatelard',
            'codePostal' => 42820,
            'etat' => 'France',
            'commune' => [
                'id' => 16418,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$key = 'localisation.adresse.commune.id';

function getValueByKeyRecursively($a, $key)
{
    $keyList = explode('.', $key);
    $currentKey = array_shift($keyList);

    // Found the value
    if (empty($currentKey)) {
        return $a;
    }

    // No more depth to traverse or no such key
    if (!is_array($a) || !array_key_exists($currentKey, $a)) {
        return null;
    }

    return getValueByKeyRecursively($a[$currentKey], implode('.', $keyList));
}

var_dump(getValueByKeyRecursively($a, $key)); // outputs: int(16418)
```

#### Iterative variant

```
function getValueByKey(array $a, $key)
{
    $keyList = explode('.', $key);
    $returnValue = $a;

    do {
        $currentKey = array_shift($keyList);

        // Found the value
        if ($currentKey === null) {
            break;
        }

        // No more depth to traverse or no such key
        if (!is_array($returnValue) || !array_key_exists($currentKey, $returnValue)) {
            return null;
        }

        $returnValue = $returnValue[$currentKey];

    } while (true);

    return $returnValue;
}

var_dump(getValueByKey($a, $key)); // outputs: int(16418)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i think i'm going to take the recurcive one wich looks exactly what i want :D thans !

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$str = '{
        "localisation" : {
            "adresse" : {
                "adresse1" : "Le Chatelard",
                "codePostal" : "42820",
                "etat" : "France",
                "commune" : {
                    "id" : 16418
                }
            }
        }
    }
        ';

$data = json_decode($str, true);
$var = $data['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id'] ;
echo $var ;
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Sorry but i think there is a mistake in my question. I don' have any problem for decoding json into an array : my problem is i can't write `$data['localisation']['adresse']['commune']['id']` in PHP because i don't know these values : they are dynamics. It could be localisation.geoloc.gps.latitude, or information.description, or services.room... or anything else. Converting the json in php is really not the problem here, sorry

Comment: OK. I got what you want exactly,my suggestion is instead of creating dynamic variable why don't you split $keys value by '.' and use that to access values from associative array directly.

Comment: Because i don't know if there is 4 or more keys. It could be information.services.key3.key4.key5... so it's much more comfortable to convert it into ['information']['services']['key3']... etc and then try to acces it, instead of creating a recursive fonction for doing it. Also could be a big performance issue on a large set of values.